# How to create a new DataTable from two DataTable using LINQ ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, join, datatable

it's me again :D

I am learning LINQ and there is something I want to do which I couldn't do. Please do Not suggest other solution which is not Linq. Thanks.

```
    Dim dtSong As DataTable = New DataTable("Songs")
    dtSong.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Guid))
    dtSong.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    dtSong.Columns.Add("Type", GetType(String))
    dtSong.Columns.Add("AlbumID", GetType(Guid))

    Dim dtAlbum As DataTable = New DataTable("Album")
    dtAlbum.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Guid))
    dtAlbum.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))

    Dim idsong, idalbum As Guid
    idalbum = Guid.NewGuid()
    dtAlbum.Rows.Add(idalbum, "Best of")

    idsong = Guid.NewGuid()
    dtSong.Rows.Add(idsong, "You are my sunshine", "Pop", idalbum)
    idsong = Guid.NewGuid()
    dtSong.Rows.Add(idsong, "twinkle twinkle", "Pop", idalbum)
    idsong = Guid.NewGuid()
    dtSong.Rows.Add(idsong, "you are my heart", "Rock", idalbum)        


    Dim query = From x In dtSong Join y In dtAlbum
                On x.Field(Of Guid)("AlbumID") Equals
                y.Field(Of Guid)("ID")
                Where (x.Field(Of String)("Type") = "Pop")
                Select New With
                     {
                        .Name = x.Field(Of String)("Name"),
                        .Type = x.Field(Of String)("Type"),
                        .Album = y.Field(Of String)("Name")
                    }

    Dim dtnew As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable
```

I guess there is something wrong in my LINQ query. I am not allowed to use CopyToDataTable on this query. I can print out the result using a For Each loop though but I want to have a new DataTable. Thanks for the help. Sorry for poor english.

L

Comment: Use this `ObjectShredder(Of T)`-class: [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable<T> Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

Comment: Hi Blam, I just tried Dim dtnew As New DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable(). Now I got a new error, it now shows CopyToDataTable in the list of extensions but the error is saying "End of statement expected"

Comment: Thanks Tim I will read through that.